# MySQL Get All Except If

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql

I have a MySQL table and I want to extract all rows except if the column contains a specific value. Is this possible?

My table structure

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | blah | blah | boo  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  2 | blah | blah | blah |
+----+------+------+------+
|  3 | blah | blah | boo  |
+----+------+------+------+
```

So if col3 contains boo, don't extract that:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  2 | blah | blah | blah |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's certainly possible. The following code should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` != "boo"
```

If you're looking where more than one column, than add the following afterwords:

```
&& `column` != "boo"
```

for every column you need.

Assuming, of course, that you mean that you DON'T want boo. If you want only boo, then take away the exclamation point.

Comment: This is my query however I get an error. Can you spot the problem?

SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `page` ='$id' AND WHERE `season` !='*' ORDER BY `season` ASC, `episode` ASC

Comment: Take out the second Where. That should be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If by "contains" you mean "is equal to":

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column <> 'VALUE TO EXCLUDE'
```

Or if by "contains" you literally mean "contains":

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT LIKE '%VALUE TO EXCLUDE%'
```

**EDIT -- To answer your updated question:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col3 <> 'boo'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE col3 != 'boo';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following excludes col3 if it equals 'boo'.

`select * from mytable where col3 <> 'boo'`

Other than that, I don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Due to the way my table is structured this would not be possible.

Comment: @Ben:  please post an example of your table structure to add some lubrication to the discussion.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, please explain. I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

select * from MyTable where col3 <> 'boo'

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in your where clause if your cloumn data and requirement are not simple.

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]+';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar NOT REGEXP '[[:alnum:]]+';
```